# How to combine two versions of the python3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv, versions

I need some advice.

I have a custom module requires version Python3.5 during installation or later versions. (no critical for run my script)

My script will simultaneously use "some_decoder.pyc" file which was compiled under Python3.3 (legacy) and need this version for run. (critical for run)

How I can to solve this problem if I use Linux and virtualenv?

I have one idea in two steps:

1. I install basic module under global environment (Python3.5).
2. I will create an environment which inherit basic modules but use python3.3 (in Windows I was able to do so)

But I hope that this problem can be solved in a different way, or redirect me where this problem was solved.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just rewrite the module or the program in one of the versions? As both are in python3.x, there shouldn't be too many things you need to fix.

Comment: Module - is a corporate and global. It is supported constantly and is able to work with new versions of the interpreter.

File - decoder (it is compiled) (there is another file: encoder) heritage from the previous team. And it contains an intricate compression and encryption scheme.

When I wrote my script, I just used the function from an early application that uses this encoder file.

Yes, I can rewrite the file, but it's long and difficult, I need to research a lot.